# Convert Dataframe to Dictionary where Some Cells Contain Lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is structured like this:

| ID | CustRef |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 111 |
| 1 | 222 |
| 2 | 333, 444, 555, 666 |

It is simple enough to convert it to a dictionary using `to_dict` but where there are multiple CustRefs I would like those values to be converted to a list.

So, in this example the dict would be:

```
result_dict = {'0': 111, '1': 222, '2': [333, 444, 555, 666}}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` and rework depending on the number of items:

```
s = df['CustRef'].str.split(', ')
s.loc[s.str.len().le(1)] = s.str[0]

out = dict(zip(df['ID'], s))
```

Or, using pure python:

```
out = {k: next(iter(l), None) if len(l:=v.split(', '))<2 else l
       for k,v in zip(df['ID'], df['CustRef'])}
```

output:

```
{0: '111', 1: '222', 2: ['333', '444', '555', '666']}
```

If you really need to use `to_dict` (e.g., to modify to handle more columns):

```
s = df['CustRef'].str.split(', ')
out = (df
   .assign(CustRef=df['CustRef'].where(s.str.len().le(1), s))
   .set_index('ID')['CustRef']
   .to_dict()
)
```